# How do I draw a geodesic line through map edges in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, maps, coordinates, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to draw geodesic line with [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/). It works fine when difference between points' longitudes is less than 180. Otherwise, e.g. longitudes are 179 and -179, OpenLayers draws line with greatest distance.

So I found a solution for straight line:

1. Checking if difference between longitudes is more than 180
2. Calculating intersection of needed line and map edge (finding temporary point with longitude 180 or -180)
3. Creating `ol.geom.MultiLineString` with array `[[firstPoint, temporaryPoint], [temporaryPoint, secondPoint]]`
4. Creating feature with line

And it works fine. But it's pretty complicated to make this trick for geodesic line with [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/). The main problem is in calculation of intersection.

[image]

I supposed to find solution in OpenLayers documentation or [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/flight-animation.html) but there is no any example with map edge intersection.

Comment: OFF-TOPIC: why the hostility in your picture?

Comment: @JonatasWalker no longer :)

Comment: Hahaha .. much better :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of investigation I found a solution. That looks like a trick but it works fine.

First of all here is an original code from [arc.js documentation](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/blob/gh-pages/README.md):

```
var start = { x: currentPoint.longitude, y: currentPoint.latitude },
    end = { x: nextPoint.longitude, y: nextPoint.latitude },
    generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start, end),
    arcLine = generator.Arc(1000 ,{offset:10});
```

The main issue is [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) can't calculate coordinates for line that intersects [International Date Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line). So I decided to move points into one tile before calculating [Great Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).

I had to find longitudes offset:

```
var dateLineOffset = 180 - currentPoint.longitude;
```

It also could be `nextPoint.longitude`. Depends on what point is placed left.

After that you can use [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) to generate coordinates:

```
var start = { x: -180, y: currentPoint.latitude },
    end = { x: nextPoint.longitude + dateLineOffset, y: nextPoint.latitude },
    generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start, end),
    arcLine = generator.Arc(1000 ,{offset:10});
```

Then you need to iterate generated coordinates and fix offset. In my case I used **map**.

```
var coordinatesWithOffset = arcLine.geometries[0].coords,
    geodesicLineCoordinates = coordinatesWithOffset.map(function(coord) {
        return ol.proj.fromLonLat([coord[0] - dateLineOffset, coord[1]]);
    }),
    geodesicLine = ol.geom.LineString(geodesicLineCoordinates);
```

That's it. `geodesicLine` will contain proper coordinates.

[image]